# Sum of 4 random variables such that their sum is 1 and each is U(0,1)

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm trying to formulate a way to generate a random set of 4 numbers that sum to 1 (a discrete probability distribution) such that each is uniform, ~$U(0,1)$. They obviously can't be iid, and normalized uniforms have a mean 0.25 which is way too low for our purposes. The way I've been trying to tackle it is by giving each one a 25% chance of coming from a "bigger" distribution.

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ iid ~$U(0,1)$ and $Y$ with support $(0,\infty)$. Let $A={X_1\over X_1+X_2+X_3+Y}, B={Y\over X_1+X_2+X_3+Y}$. Find the $F_Y$ such that ${1\over 4}f_B(z)+{3\over 4}f_A(z)=1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean of each of them will have to be $0.25$ if they come from the same distribution because means add.  The easiest approach is to pull four numbers from $U(0,1)$ and normalize them by dividing by the sum.  This will give each a distribution which ranges all the way up to $1$, but there will be little density there.

Comment: Yeah the means adding makes total sense. I tried the U(0,1) thing first, and there's just too little density up there for our purposes. I also tried to scale things by "bigger" distributions and didn't like how dramatic the dropoff in the middle was. I'll keep messing around. Thanks.

Comment: The point is you can't have four big numbers sum to $1$.  They need to be small.  That is what the means being additive means.  You are asking the impossible.

Comment: You're right and I'm not disputing that - you _can_ do better than normalizing uniform randoms by the sum. The Kullback-Leibler divergence for that distribution:

Comment: you are correct and I don't dispute that U(0,1) is impossible, and that whatever function I use to generate the values must have a mean of 0.25. However, you _can_ do better than normalizing uniform randoms by their sum. The Kullback-Leibler divergence for that distribution is 1.83. If we instead use a procedure where we pick one of the four numbers to be drawn from a uniform, and the other three to have a sum of 1 minus that number, the divergence drops to 0.445. I am curious about optimizing this, but this question is poorly posed. Thanks for your help.